# Mapforce Flex Text as target to make EDI fixed length file

Tags: edi, map-force, fixed-length-file

I need to use Altova Mapforce and it's Flex-Text as a target feature to make a fixed length file. I will be pulling data from two sources--one holds employees, the other holds dependents of the employees. The employees have a certain set of fixed length fields, and the dependents have a different set of fixed length fields. The dependents will be tied to employees based upon the employee SSN--the Dependent record will have the Employee SSN in it also.

The end result will be one .txt fixed length file where the employees and dependents will be "interweaved" in such a way that an employee's dependents appear immediately after the employee record.

Flex-text seems pretty straight forward, but going backwards and using flex-text as target is kind of blowing my mind.

Does anyone have some experience and can give me direction?